# What is the meaning of ‘neutral’ in the following article?

Tags: phonology

Source: (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology)

> In General American and Canada, /l/ is generally dark, but to varying degrees: before stressed vowels it is neutral or only slightly velarized.[17] In southern U.S. accents it is noticeably clear between vowels, and in some other positions.

Comment: In this context, it means 'not significantly velarized'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "not velarized."  (" only slightly velarized" would mean that it can be, but not significantly.)